# Using jquery with a-frame recieving undefined error

Tags: jquery, aframe, webvr

I'm trying to use JQUERY with A-Frame (WebVR) but it's not working. When I include a JQUERY-Statement the console in my webbrowser shows an undefined error.

How can I use JQUERY with A-Frame, or does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($("#video").buffered);
});

     </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$("#video")` returns an array containing the video element and some utility functions. To grab the video `element`, just check the first element `$("#video")[0]`

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/Ljtnvczh/3/).